# My New-RandomPassword function suddenly doesn't work

Tags: powershell

For fun, I decided to create a function that would generate some random passwords based on how many the user decides they want. I'm using Begin and Process blocks to run the script. The Begin block has a $characterPool variable with the alphanumeric and special characters as potential characters. The Process block asks how many passwords the user wants and creates that many random 12 character passwords. When I first created the function, it worked fine. Now, no matter how many passwords I request, only two are created, then it re-asks the question. Afterward, hitting enter with an empty string or adding another number causes one password to print out.

```
Begin
    {
        $characterPool = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    }
    Process
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Password = -join ($characterPool | Get-Random -Count 12)
            }
        $counter = Read-Host -Prompt "How many passwords do ya want, buddy?"
        1..$counter | New-RandomPassword
    }
```

I would expect this to generate the number of passwords that I've requested. There's no error being generated, it simply displays like the following:

```
Begin
    {
        $characterPool = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    }
    Process
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Password = -join ($characterPool | Get-Random -Count 12)
            }
        $counter = Read-Host -Prompt "How many passwords do ya want, buddy?"
        1..$counter | New-RandomPassword
    }

How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 5
Password    
--------    
1z@p8Jgl52yU
1#K8z2@iA!&o
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 
Pw!C#d2xTjMu
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 
fo*Oca9HbRQr
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 
omzCRpwqdOfM
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 
u5lMN!kjhzfe
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?: 6
vLaxHq945K$D
How many passwords do ya want, buddy?:
```

Comment: This PowerShell does not work for me as I get a " The term 'New-RandomPassword' is not recognized". Is your posted script complete?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean: It looks like `New-RandomPassword` is the name of the function being defined (even though the code doesn't show that), and you're seeing a recursive invocation - which is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Read-Host` prompt function to the start and move the password generation logic into a loop:

```bsh
function New-RandomPassword {
    param()

    [int]$counter = Read-Host -Prompt "How many passwords do ya want, buddy?"
    $characterPool = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    $i = 0;
    while($i++ -lt $counter)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Password = -join ($characterPool | Get-Random -Count 12)
        }
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to call the function recursively.

---

I'd personally turn the `$counter` variable into a parameter and then prompt the user in a script that *calls* `New-RandomPassword` internally

```bsh
function New-RandomPassword {
    param(
        [ValidateRange(1,500)]
        [int]$Count
    )

    $characterPool = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    $i = 0;
    while($i++ -lt $count)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Password = -join ($characterPool | Get-Random -Count 12)
        }
    }
}
```

---

As [mklement0 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823350/my-new-randompassword-function-suddenly-doesnt-work/58823698#comment103924497_58823698), you can also assign an expression with the `Read-Host` call as a default value for the parameter:

```
param(
    [ValidateRange(1,500)]
    [int]$Count = $(Read-Host 'How many passwords do ya want, buddy?')
)
```

I personally consider this an anti-pattern, and would rather insist on either defaulting to `1` or marking the parameter `Mandatory`:

```
# If the caller omits the argument, 1 password is returned
param(
    [ValidateRange(1,500)]
    [int]$Count = 1
)
```

or

```
# Caller _must_ supply a parameter argument (the default console host will prompt the user if not, but depends on the host application)
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateRange(1,500)]
    [int]$Count
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. As for it being an anti-pattern: In a simple case such as this (scalar input, implicit casting to the target type works), I think it is actually superior to `Mandatory`, due to the poor UX that the latter provides - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4068. Since `Read-Host` too fails with `-noninteractive` (as you would want here), there's no real downside. Overall, though, the better solution would obviously be to fix the automatic prompting mechanism (or, failing that, get rid of it altogether).

Comment: @mklement0 fair point. In this particular case though, from a ux perspective, when I call a function `New-RandomPassword` with no args, I'd expect it to just, you know... provide me with a new random password :D

Comment: :) That's a good point too; so the real UX problem here is that a prompt is being displayed _at all_, not how it is implemented.